# Последнее входящее сообщение в SQlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Работаю с базой данных. имеется колонка MESSAGE , а так же колонка OUTGOING. OUTGOING принимает значение 0 или 1 в зависимости от того сообщение входящее или нет. как мне получить последнее входящее сообщение?

Comment: Если кроме этих двух колонок никаких больше нет, то никак

Comment: Какие колонки (поля) есть еще в таблице?

Comment: FROM_USER,TO_USER, DATE и тд тп

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT MESSAGE FROM база.таблица where OUTGOING = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`

С order by id аккуратно, мне не известно как у вас вставляются записи в бд.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY MESSAGE DESC LIMIT 1;
```